# How to find records with partial FROM ... TO values?

Tags: mysql, autocomplete

I have DB with the following values

```
! # ! FROM ! TO   !
!===!======!=======
! 1 ! aaaa ! aabb !
! 2 ! aa10 ! aa2a !
! 3 ! bb   ! cc   !
! 4 ! bb 20! bb 30!
! 5 ! bccc ! bccd !
```

FROM and TO can span any range. All suported charachters are allowed. FROM and TO can have different length. The DB has ~800'000 rows. The rows have mor columns which are important for the use case.

For an **autocomplete field** I have to find all records which do match somewhere between (including) FROM and TO.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table WHERE (
  '11' BETWEEN from AND to
)
```

Unfortunately this does not match for FROM=1105 and TO=1110 .

How would the correct query for this look like?

Comment: Assuming standard alphabetical sorting, `bb` and `cc` are both after `b`, so not sure why `b` matches that row in your output. How exactly are you planning on mapping input to the FROM and TO values?

Comment: Your examples are very vague and the order doesn't seem to follow a reliable pattern, are you able to clarify your aims at all?

Comment: When the user types 'b', all rows that start with a 'b', and all rows with  possibel values between FROM and TO that start with a 'b' have to match.

Comment: What matches if the user enters `c`? What about `bcccx`?

Comment: Only row #3 should match, since no other row does start with a c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: The question was changed a bit, so replacing the answer since I'm at 0 anyway :)

What you want is something similar to; ('b' being the string searched for, note it's mentioned twice in the question)

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 'b'
  BETWEEN SUBSTR(`FROM`, 1, CHAR_LENGTH('b')) 
      AND `TO`;
```

Of course if you know the string you're searching for and the length of it, you can replace the `CHAR_LENGTH()` in actual code.

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaa07/2)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I don't understand what it's doing.

Comment: @BetaRide On second thought, I suspect it's the second, simpler, version I added that you want. If it indeed is the first, I can add some explanation.

Comment: As mentioned in the improoved question, this misses most of the rows I'm looking for. Most of the time I do not have the full string (which is actually the idea of an autocomplete field).